# Full pairwise summary table for GLMs in R

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to run a logistic model using 4 different predictor variables: Depth (continuous), DPM (2 levels), Proximity (3 levels), and Area (2 levels). I know this many interactions makes things complicated, but was wondering if it's possible to produce a summary table with all pairwise interactions (and Depth). Thank you very much for any help. The code is:

`mod <- glm(cbind(Towards, Total-Towards) ~ DPM*Proximity*Depth*Area,data=Data, family=binomial('logit'))`

I greatly appreciate any and all help.

Some Data to fix ideas:

```
Data <- structure(list(Towards = c(4, 7, 9, 0, 15, 10, 11, 23, 1, 4), Total = c(6, 14,
    10, 7, 15, 12, 20, 41, 5, 8), Depth = c(-0.3, -0.25, -0.21, -0.17, -0.05, 0,
    0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.56), DPM = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    2L), .Label = c("Post", "Pre" ), class = "factor"), Proximity =
    structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("East",
    "Far", "Near" ), class = "factor"), Area = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L,
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Control", "Control‌​", "DPM"), class =
    "factor")), .Names = c("Towards", "Total", "Depth", "DPM", "Proximity",
    "Area"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's probably possible but you need to take into consideration that you will eventually have to interpret these coefficients. If you have a problem doing it could you be more precise? Try providing an example we can reproduce.

Comment: I could provide some sample data if that would help, but the last few lines of the summary table look like:                                                                    
DPMPost:ProximityFar:Depth:AreaDPM   6.86862    2.93579   2.340   0.0193 *
DPMPost:ProximityNear:Depth:AreaDPM  1.08910    2.29398   0.475   0.6350        I understand that it's using reference levels, but it also doesn't allow me to ever compare that level of Proximity and Area but with a different level of DPM. Please let me know if that doesn't help. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes please provide some data. It's very difficult to understand your issue presented that way.

Comment: 'Towards <- c(4,7,9,0,15,10,11,23,1,4)  <br/> Total<-c(6,14,10,7,15,12,20,41,5,8)  <br/>  Depth<-c(-.3,-.25,-.21,-.17,-.05,0,0,.25,.5,.56)  <br/>  DPM<-c("Pre","Post","Pre","Pre","Post","Pre","Post","Post","Post","Pre")  <br/>  Proximity<-c("Far","Near","East","East","East","Near","Far","Far","Near","Far")  <br/>  Area<-c("DPM","Control","Control","DPM","Control","Control","DPM","DPM","Control","DPM")  <br/> Data<-data.frame(Towards,Total, Depth, DPM, Proximity, Area)'

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't seem to get the example in a script format. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry for the delay you can use `dput(Data)` to post the data on SO.

Comment: You seem to have triple interactions as well with your data. I would suggest starting with a simple model you understand then making it more complex little by little. It's difficult to start with one complicated model. Take a look at the [effect package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html). It might help for the interactions.

Comment: Thanks much for your help. I'll explore the package, see what I can produce. Thanks again!